# What is UPDATE_NOOP in firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

We created a dashboard for Firestore operations on stackdriver. 
We got **CREATE**, **UPDATE** and **UPDATE_NOOP** as the operations done in **document writes** metric.

I couldn't understand what does **UPDATE_NOOP** signifies.

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE_NOOP` happens when you are trying to update the document in Firestore with exactly the same data. In my experience, UPDATE_NOOP does contribute to billing, though I couldn't find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

[NOOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_(code)) traditionally stands for "NO OPeration".  So I would guess that it counts update operations that don't actually change any data in a document.

Comment: I though so but I was not sure, so if we can find this thing documented some where it will be great.

Comment: It doesn't exactly show up In a web search, so if you want formal documentation, you might have to ask Google cloud support.

Comment: Your profile says "Google Developer Advocate (Firebase)" but your answer is unhelpful.

Comment: @Nakilon Thanks for your feedback.  Do you have a different idea of what this means, given that it's currently not documented?